# android searchView in action bar how to use it?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a `SearchView` in a `ActionBar`. Now I want to use it but I don't know how to use it. In the custom `SearchView` I use it like this:

```
    SearchView sear = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
sear.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()

                                          {
                                              @Override
                                              public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query){
                                                  return false;
                                              }
                                              @Override
                                              public boolean onQueryTextChange (String newText){
                                                  listDataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                                                  return true;
                                              }
                                          }

        );
```

Now I have `SearchView` in an action bar which I show through code:

```
public class DataListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView =
                (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_Exit:
                openExit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void openExit() {
}
```

How can I use `SearchView` ? I don't know how to use `SearchView` in action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Set the onQueryTextListener(..) similar to what you have mentioned in your question on the searchView.

Comment: but where i put the onquerrytextlistener code because it not working below thw on create